# Test taking : ji选?

Tags: vocabulary

During test taking I've heard people talking about ji选.

Which apparently is pretty much just "guessing" at the answer or as one person told me - just picking which ever answer 'looks' good.

So what exactly is the 'ji' from ji选?

What exactly does it mean?

How did it come about?

edit: should be ... 机选
Means 'computer picked' or 'random'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a 随 (sui2) dropped in 随机 （randomly）.

Therefore (随)机选 means "randomly picked".

As for 'computer picked', It would still be translated as "randomly" because computers pick numbers "randomly." In this case, 机 could mean 机器 （Machine）.

Answer (score 1):

you can choose both of them.

机选 is used as an opposite of 手选, which means to be chosed by hands. Both of these words are used in picking numbers for lotteries.

There is no official fully word for 机选. But it means to use the numbers chosen by the machine (机器) randomly (随机).